# How can I make a for inside another for in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a cursor that returns:

```
id, name, mes, dia
id name mes dia
1  ex   1   1
1  ex   1   2
2  ex   1   1
2  ex   1   2
3  ex   1   1
3  ex   1   3
```

I need two use a function to make something for each id (person) in each day.
Something like that:

```
for iten in c1
loop
  foor iten1 in ci.id
  loop
    foor iten2 in iten1.dia
    loop
    -----------do someting
    end loop;
  end loop;
end loop;
```

Any idea about how can I do it in Oracle?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what "make something for each id" means?

Comment: Why do you need the nested loops at all - isn't the current cursor already giving you one result per ID per day?

Answer (score 0):

You ask for something like this:

```
FORrFicheros IN c1
   LOOP
     IF c1.name LIKE 'lihova%'
     THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Something1');

     ELSIF c1.name LIKE'erprva%'
     THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Something2');
         FOR i IN c2
         LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Something3');
         END LOOP;

       END;
     END if;
   END LOOP;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with the question. It isn't looking for logic around the name and where did `c2` come from? From the pseudocode the OP seems to be trying to access a subset of the values returned by the original cursor, but it isn't really clear...